# how to read file from browser using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, tomcat8

On localhost:8181 I am getting following error

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jan 31 14:56:30 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied

Answer (score 0):

Add `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` in **application.properties** file

Refer [Official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-whitelabel-error-page)

Comment: This is not going to solve the actual error. It's only going to alter how the error is being displayed.